# What is the difference between horizontal units and horizontal scale at an oscilloscope?

Tags: electricity, oscillators, electrical-engineering, data-analysis, data

> This is a picture of the data of a given measurement by an oscilloscope. I would like to know what the difference between horizontal units and horizontal scale at an oscilloscope is. I would be so so grateful if someone could shed some light on it! :)
> [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Horizontal Unit "s"** means that the horizontal axis represents time and the units of the axis is seconds.

**Horizontal Scale "1e-4"** means that the one horizontal tick is $10^{-4}$ units.

Overall that means that the width of each box on the oscilloscope screen corresponds to a time interval of 100 microseconds

Comment: Thank you so much Hilmar!!

Answer (score 0):

Each horizontal division (spacing of grid lines) is likely "[Horizontal Scale] [Horizontal Units]", which is $10^{-4}\ \text{s}$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you so much Puk!